# Can't use GWTquery in GWT

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, gwt, gwtquery

I am trying to use GWTQuery in my GWT project. For that, i downloaded the `jar` file from the official source. Then I added it to the `lib` folder within the `WEB-INF` folder, and configured the build path to include that. After that, i did all the necessary imports, which are showing no error, thus proving that they have been successfully imported.

However while using a simple selector function like `$("#child").text('foo');`, I am getting an error message **No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery; did you forget to inherit a required module?**. Can anyone tell me why is this happening, and how might I correct it?

This is no Maven setup, so please don't suggest one!  (This is the XML file:)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgotten the inherits tag to be included in your .gwt.xml file

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.query.Query'/>
```

Ensure you follow each step from the guideline wiki - http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/GettingStarted#Introduction

You should use a **Source Tab View** to edit the XML file if you are not comfortable with the **Design Tab View**

[image]

Comment: Switch from to the "source" view (at the bottom of the tab), or open the file in something else than Eclipse.

Comment: Okay, done that. now I am getting no URL, instead a `[ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method` error..What now?

Comment: @SSR: the error is not about GwtQuery-UI, it's about GwtQuery, the module name is `com.google.gwt.query.Query`, the _Getting Started_ page is at https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: Yeah it's fine now. I messed up along with SSR! Blind copy pasting!